# Use columns as where and has subtraction in it

Tags: sql, sql-server

My problem is I just wanna show all the unpaid rows:

I have this data:

```
id   name      commission    paid
1    James     15000         2000
2    Curry     15000         15000
3    Durant    15000         0
4    Wade      15000         5000
5    Harden    15000         15000
```

I wanted to get only the rows that are not gonna be equal to 0, I wanted to use where clause for `commission - paid` if it is greater than 0

Output that I would expect is:

```
id   name      commission    paid
1    James     15000         2000
3    Durant    15000         0
4    Wade      15000         5000
```

Comment: You can use { where ( commission - paid) >0 }

Comment: Why is there `Durant`? He has `0` paid

Comment: Are you using MySQL or MS SQL Server?

Comment: @StepUp because `15000` subtracted `0` is 15000 still

Comment: @jarlh Im doing both actually, MS SQL is for migration and MySQL is what we are currently using

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Im writing `MS SQL`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE (commission - paid) > 0
```

Or

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE commission!=paid
```

This will work too because either subtraction will be greater than zero or 0 (assuming paid amount is always less than commission)

Comment: very cleaver ill make it the correct answer, thanks mate!

Comment: seems like the second one will be good for performance I suggest go with the second query. But go for the second one only if having a limited scope of a project

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following solution using a simple calculation on `WHERE`:

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE commission - paid > 0
```

You can also use the following:

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE commission > paid
```

**Note:** In this case someone can overpay the commission. Using `!=` or `<>` the overpay would be found as not paid.

> **demo:** https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=a391576f2df2c5d7c8616485b2c70099

---

To get all paid rows you can use the following:

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE commission - paid <= 0
```

or ...

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE commission <= paid
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use the following query given below using `WHERE` clause

```
SELECT * FROM commision_table_name WHERE (commission - paid) > 0;
```